# CSS current window size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying some thing like making the background of the whole body part.

```
<html>
<head><head/>
<body>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

in this case how do i get the height and width of the current body cause i show a popup other than that i want to blur the whole background.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.

Comment: You want to **know** the dimensions of the background? That's JS. Or just use em to style a div or something. That would be CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your wrapper to go full window height and width, you will need to add a few attributes to your `html` and `body` elements.

Try something like this:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    color: black;
    -moz-opacity: .2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    z-index: 1;
}
```

or something similar?

Comment: I will second this, but only add that you may need to add `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; }` first.